# Implement safe transaction with dependable queries

Tags: php, yii, transactions

How implement safe transactions while a query needs to have previous query's result?
I'm using Yii framework.
According to Yii example of using CDbTransaction:

```
$transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
try
{
   $connection->createCommand($sql1)->execute();
   $connection->createCommand($sql2)->execute();//what if $sql2 needs result of $sql1 
   //.... other SQL executions
   $transaction->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   $transaction->rollback();
}
```

Comment: that's fine, that can work! or you can use another connection to get independent result

Comment: Yes it's working.Sorry, I misunderstood Yii CDbCommand execute().